# Import Messy Text File Into Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, import, text-files, python-import

I am trying to load in a really messy text file into Python/Pandas. Here is an example of what the data in the file looks like

Data Analytics v2.2.1 - Price Activity Data - Ticker1.txtData for: 2017-12-01 02:13:00 UTC - 2017-12-31 18:12:00 UTCGenerated: 2018-01-16 19:44:53 UTCticker    date    description sector  industry    Price-R T1-volume   V-dispersion    Price-delta volume-delta    center-date center-time center-time-zoneTicker1 2017-12-01 02:13:00 Company Inc.    N/A N/A 0.0 1   1.0 0.0 1.0 2017-11-30  21:13:00    US/EasternTicker1   2017-12-01 06:27:00 Company Inc.    N/A N/A 0.0 1   1.0 0.0 1.0 2017-12-01  01:27:00    US/Eastern

I have tried Pandas pd.read_csv function with the separator " ". However, due to the initial note, it looks like not working properly.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('Ticker1.txt', sep=" ", 
                   names = ['ticker',   'date', 'description',  'sector',   'industry', 'raw-s',    's-volume', 's-dispersion', 'raw-s-delta',  'volume-delta', 'center-date',  'center-time',  'center-time-zone'])
```

File data:

Data Analytics v2.2.1 - Price Activity Data - Ticker1.txtData for: 2017-12-01 02:13:00 UTC - 2017-12-31 18:12:00 UTCGenerated: 2018-01-16 19:44:53 UTCticker    date    description sector  industry    Price-R T1-volume   V-dispersion    Price-delta volume-delta    center-date center-time center-time-zoneTicker1 2017-12-01 02:13:00 Company Inc.    N/A N/A 0.0 1   1.0 0.0 1.0 2017-11-30  21:13:00    US/EasternTicker1   2017-12-01 06:27:00 Company Inc.    N/A N/A 0.0 1   1.0 0.0 1.0 2017-12-01  01:27:00    US/Eastern

Expected Result:

Initial note is there for information only and should be ignored.

"Data Analytics v2.2.1 - Price Activity Data - Ticker1.txtData for: 2017-12-01 02:13:00 UTC - 2017-12-31 18:12:00 UTCGenerated: 2018-01-16 19:44:53 UTC"

Columns:

'ticker','date','description','sector','industry','Price-R','T1-volume','V-dispersion','Price-delta','volume-delta','center-date','center-time','center-time-zone'

Data:

Ticker1 2017-12-01 02:13:00 Company Inc.    N/A N/A 0.0 1   1.0 0.0 1.0 2017-11-30  21:13:00    US/Eastern

Ticker1 2017-12-01 06:27:00 Company Inc.    N/A N/A 0.0 1   1.0 0.0 1.0 2017-12-01  01:27:00    US/Eastern

Comment: Try `pd.read_csv('Ticker1.txt', skiprows=1, sep='\t')`? I hope the file doesn't have `' '` as a separator given that description appears to have spaces in the field.

Answer (score 0):

pandas `read_csv()` has a number of builtins (like `skiprows`) to deal with issues like this.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have 3 rows, that you want to skip:

```
import pandas as pd

labels_read = ['ticker','date','d0','d1','sector','industry','Price-R','T1-volume','V-dispersion','Price-delta','volume-delta','center-date','center-time','center-time-zone']
labels = ['ticker','date','description','sector','industry','Price-R','T1-volume','V-dispersion','Price-delta','volume-delta','center-date','center-time','center-time-zone']
df = pd.read_csv("test1.csv",sep=" ",skiprows=3, names=labels_read)
df['description'] = df['d0'].str.cat(df['d1'],sep=" ")
df = df[labels]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @PySeeker and @jtwilson for answers. Appreciate your quick reply. Skiprows parameter helped me. However I had to use few tricks to decide the row-number. This trick may not be efficient but I was able to understand that and therefore I used it.

```py
""" Need to print first few lines to understand where the header starts"""

lines = []

for line in pd.read_csv('Ticker1.txt', encoding='utf-8', header=None, chunksize=1):
    lines.append(line.iloc[0,0])

print(lines[0:4])

""" 

1. Its a tab delimiter file
2. Looks like first 4 lines need to be ignored

"""


import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('Ticker1.txt', sep="\t", skiprows = 4)

data.columns = ['ticker',   'date', 'description',  'sector',   'industry', 'raw-s',    's-volume', 's-dispersion', 'raw-s-delta',  'volume-delta', 'center-date',  'center-time',  'center-time-zone']

data.head()
```